# iAd banner doesn't load at all for iPhone 6/6+

Tags: ios, xcode, simulator, adbannerview

Is it possible to turn something off in Xcode 6.1 that no matter if the iAdBannerView is implemented correctly, the ads won't show on iPhone 6,6+ simulator? I have my official Xcode project and I made a duplicate of official Xcode project. In my duplicate Xcode project the banners load on iPhone 6/6+. Then i copied and pasted iAd integration and implementation into official Xcode project and connected everything exactly the same yet for official project iPhone 6/6+ won't load the ads at all. Even when I clicked Alpha=1, the White strip didn't appear in place of ad. Is there somewhere in Xcode 6.1 that disabled iAds even with correct integration/implementation?

Answer (score 0):

No there is no button in Xcode that disables ads. There must be something wrong with your code. Post your code for ad integration and i'll help you if I can.